# Find a number nearest to all numbers in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization, numbers

This problem is basically an algorithm optimization problem.

We have a list which has n elements. for e.g. `{n1,n2,n3...nk}`
This list is sorted and we have to find out the number ni which is

1. `n1<=ni<=nk`
2. The sum of distance of `ni` from each number is minimum.

There may be total `(nk-n1+1)` possible numbers but our objective is to find out the number `ni` which is
nearest to all other numbers.

Brute force approach could be iterate through `n1` to nk and calculate the sum of distance
from all list numbers. This way easily we can figure out the number who is closest to all other numbers in the list.

But the problem with this approach is, it is not good in terms of time complexity. The time complexity of this approach is `O(n^2)`.

I think there could be better method to do this which can solve this problem with less time 
complexity.

Any approach will be appreciated.

Comment: What definition of "distance" do you use?

Comment: How about searching with binary search cos you mentioned that list is sorted?

Comment: yes distance(a,b)=abs(a-b)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If by "distance" you mean `distance(a,b) = abs(a-b)` then you simply need to find the median.

Finding the median in a sorted list is O(1).

Comment: you might mean "medoid" (its value coincides with the median in 1d case for the given distance definition (`abs(a-b)`) if there are odd number of elements).

Comment: @Sebastian: Yes I do. If there are an even number of elements, then either/both medoids will do.

Comment: Yes if there are even number of elements . then nearest number should be average of two middle numbers. if b1 and b2 are two middle numbers then nearest number should be (b1+b2)/2.

Comment: how to get median in O(1) in sorted list ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer should be ROUND( SUM(n1,...,nk)/k ) .

Answer (score 0):

Find the average ... this takes O(n).
Then walk through the list to find ni for the average (also takes O(n))... actually more like o(1/2n)